# Replace line which matches string containing slashes?

Tags: regex, sed

I have a file like this:

```
/foo/bar/asdf
asdf/foo/bar/qwerty
/qwerty/foo/asdf
/asdf/qwerty/bar
```

And I want to remove any lines which don't contain `/bar/`, so that the desired output is:

```
/foo/bar/asdf
asdf/foo/bar/qwerty
```

I tried using different characters for delimiters, e.g. colons: `sed \:/blocks/:!d`*`file`*`-i`, however it doesn't seem to delete anything.

Comment: All you needed was to put your `sed` expression in quotes, i.e. `sed '\:/bar/:!d' file`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this sed command,

```
sed -n '/\/bar\//p' file
```

It prints all the lines which contain `/bar/` string,

**Example:**

```
$ cat rr.txt
/foo/bar/asdf
asdf/foo/bar/qwerty
/qwerty/foo/asdf
/asdf/qwerty/bar

$ sed -n '/\/bar\//p' rr.txt
/foo/bar/asdf
asdf/foo/bar/qwerty
```

Comment: place sed inline edit `-i` option to make changes on the file.

Answer (score 1):

An `awk` solution.

```
awk '/\/bar\//' file
/foo/bar/asdf
asdf/foo/bar/qwerty
```